# Summary statistics for a set of polygons

Tags: software-recommendations, spatial-statistics, statistics

I have a set of a few millions polygons on which I'd like to compute summary statistics.

I do know that what is relevant will depend on my needs, but I wonder if there is some agreed upon summary statistics that I can use to start my exploratory analysis. If that helps, one can assume that all polygons have been centred (their centroid is 0).

Basically, the geometric version of what I'd get from panda's `describe` method (stuff like area distribution, perimeter, number of vertices, perimeter squared / area, (convex hull area) / area, aspect ratio…).

Brownie point if there's a Python lib or PostGIS function that implements that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs.html) and modify this function to do whatever you want:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from timeit import default_timer as timer

file = r"/home/bera/Drives/data1/data/LMV/Topografi50/221121/fb9f40f8-f882-4243-87ce-5fa19b36cdf9/mark_ln18/mark_ln18.gpkg"
df = gpd.read_file(file)

#df.shape
#Out[47]: (53283, 8)

def desc(geometry):
    perimiter = geometry.length
    area = geometry.area
    vertexcount = len(geometry.wkt.split(","))
    hullarea = geometry.convex_hull.area
    #Add more rows for all the calculations you want
    return [perimiter, area, vertexcount, hullarea]

start = timer()
df['perimiter'], df['area'], df['vertexcount'], df['hullarea'] = zip(*df['geometry'].map(desc))
stop = timer()
print(f"Rows/second: {round(df.shape[0]/(stop-start), 2)}")
#Rows/second: 29373.24

df[df.columns[-4:]].head()
#     perimiter          area  vertexcount      hullarea
# 0  401.916813   9846.636037           10  10323.912105
# 1  230.775514   3865.380491           13   3865.380491
# 2  757.806254  22893.168646           62  30856.200570
# 3  807.037795  38937.367872           45  41263.927578
# 4  361.031256   7209.296858            9   7558.841741
```

Comment: Indeed, but I was wondering if such a thing already existed.